# Qt multithreading QThreads that keep a TCP connection and are reused

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I'm really unsure of how to address this problem so i will explain it first.
I need to run a number of threads that each connect to some application via TCPSocket, so far no problem. The application is quite time consuming that is why i want it to run parallel on multiple threads and one thread each to communicate with it. Once the computation is finished i want to send the results to another thread collecting the results.
Therefor i wrote a Worker class:

```
class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker();
    Worker(int port);
    ~Worker();
    QTcpSocket* sock;
    void insert();

public slots:
    void connect();
    void process(const int &id, const QString &param, const int &arity);

signals:
    void ready();
    void finished(const int &id, const int &consistent, const QString &result);
    void error(QString err);
};
```

Now that superThread is supposed to work off a huge file and needs to spread it around the threads, and then receive and handle the results. My approach so far is another superThread that is connected in the main() as follows:

```
QThread* superThread = new QThread();
supWorker* super = new supWorker();
for (int i = 0; i < nrWorkers; i++){
    Worker* worker = new Worker(portRange+i);
    QThread* workerThread = new QThread();
    QThread::connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(connect()));
    worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
    workerThread->start();
    QThread::connect(super, SIGNAL(process(int, QString, int)), worker, SLOT(process(int,QString,int)));
    QThread::connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished(int, int, QString)), super, SLOT(handleResult(int, int, QString)));
}
```

The problem this way is obviously that i can only send the SIGNAL to all connected threads. What i want the superThread to do is send arguments to only one of the threads. I don't know how i can handle the connection so that only one of the working threads receives it?

Any help or architectural ideas much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sry but I think this is way to broad for SO.

Comment: Sry, edited hoping its a little more specific now.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I got the idea 100% right, but why not pass the array of worker threads to the super thread, keep an index that denotes the index of the currently active thread, connect signals only to that one, dispatch the signals when needed, wait for completion, disconnect the signals, advance the index and repeat? If dispatching serialized signals to the threads is what you really want this could work.

**EDIT**

Ok I actually pulled myself togetger to make a Qt based sample that implements the needed workflow and put it on [github](https://github.com/rubu/QtThreadExample/tree/master).

```
#pragma once

#include <QThread>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QTimer>

#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

struct Work
{
    int m_work;
};

struct Result
{
    int m_result;
    int m_workerIndex;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Work);
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Result);

class Worker : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker(int workerIndex) : m_workerIndex(workerIndex)
    {
        moveToThread(this);
        connect(this, SIGNAL(WorkReceived(Work)), SLOT(DoWork(Work)));
        printf("[%d]: worker %d initialized\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(currentThreadId()), workerIndex);
    }

    void DispatchWork(Work work)
    {
        emit WorkReceived(work);
    }

public slots:
    void DoWork(Work work)
    {
        printf("[%d]: worker %d received work %d\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(currentThreadId()), m_workerIndex, work.m_work);
        msleep(100);
        Result result = { work.m_work * 2, m_workerIndex };
        emit WorkDone(result);
    }

signals:
    void WorkReceived(Work work);
    void WorkDone(Result result);

private:
    int m_workerIndex;
};

class Master : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Master(int workerCount) : m_activeWorker(0), m_workerCount(workerCount)
    {
        printf("[%d]: creating master thread\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(QThread::currentThreadId()));
    }
    ~Master()
    {
        std::for_each(m_workers.begin(), m_workers.end(), [](std::unique_ptr<Worker>& worker)
        {
            worker->quit();
            worker->wait();
        });
    }


public slots:
    void Initialize()
    {
        printf("[%d]: initializing master thread\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(QThread::currentThreadId()));
        for (int workerIndex = 0; workerIndex < m_workerCount; ++workerIndex)
        {
            auto worker = new Worker(workerIndex);
            m_workers.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<Worker>(worker)));
            connect(worker, SIGNAL(WorkDone(Result)), SLOT(WorkDone(Result)));
            worker->start();
        }
        m_timer = new QTimer();
        m_timer->setInterval(500);
        connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(GenerateWork()));
        m_timer->start();
    }
    void GenerateWork()
    {
        Work work = { m_activeWorker };
        printf("[%d]: dispatching work %d to worker %d\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(QThread::currentThreadId()), work.m_work, m_activeWorker);
        m_workers[m_activeWorker]->DispatchWork(work);
        m_activeWorker = ++m_activeWorker % m_workers.size();
    }
    void WorkDone(Result result)
    {
        printf("[%d]: received result %d from worker %d\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(QThread::currentThreadId()), result.m_result, result.m_workerIndex);
    }
    void Terminate()
    {
        m_timer->stop();
        delete m_timer;
    }

private:
    int m_workerCount;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Worker>> m_workers;
    int m_activeWorker;
    QTimer* m_timer;
};
```

QtThreadExample.cpp:

```
#include "QtThreadExample.hpp"
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<Work>("Work");
    qRegisterMetaType<Result>("Result");
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    QThread masterThread;
    Master master(5);
    master.moveToThread(&masterThread);
    master.connect(&masterThread, SIGNAL(started()), SLOT(Initialize()));
    master.connect(&masterThread, SIGNAL(terminated()), SLOT(Terminate()));
    masterThread.start();
    // Set a timer to terminate the program after 10 seconds
    QTimer::singleShot(10 * 1000, &application, SLOT(quit()));
    application.exec();
    masterThread.quit();
    masterThread.wait();
    printf("[%d]: master thread has finished\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(QThread::currentThreadId()));
    return 0;
}
```

In general the solution is to actually not emit a signal from the master thread itself, but emit the signal from the worker thread - this way you get a unique signal for each thread and can process the work asynchronously in the event loop and then emit back a signal that the thread is done. The sample can and should be refactored to your needs, but in general it demonstrates a producer/consumer patter in Qt using the idea with the index and signaling threads one by one. I am using a general timer to generate work in the master thread (`Master::m_timer`) - I guess in your case you will be generating work with a signal coming from a socket, file or something else. Then I call a method on an active worker thread and the method emits a signal to the event loop of the worker thread to start performing the work and then emit a signal about completion. That is a general description, look a the sample, try it out, and if you have any follow up questions let me know.

I guess this works fairly nice if you are using Qt objects, but in the traditional sense of consumer/producer patterns the signal/slot stuff actually make the life a bit harder, a standard C++11 pipeline with a `std::condition_variable` and a master thread calling [condition_variable::notify_one()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) and the worker threads simply waiting on the condition variable would be easier, however Qt has nice wrappers for all the I/O stuff. So just try this out and decide.

Below is the sample output of the example, I guess the thread logging indicates that the needed effect is achieved:
[image]

One more note, since `QApplication` runs an event loop itself, if you do not have a GUI you can actually let all your I/O objects and master class live in the main thread and emit signals from there, thus eliminating the need for a separate master thread. Of course if you have a GUI you wouldn't want to burden it with this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for the confusing question, i edited my post hoping my problem is a little more clear now. Because i don't know how to properly dispatch the signals to a specific and only one of the working threads.

Comment: @yonobi, as I mentioned, one of the possibilities is to connect only that/those thread(s) that you want to actually receive the signal. And then perform disconnections/reconnections as needed.

Comment: @yonobi, here (https://forum.qt.io/topic/12999/send-signals-to-a-specified-receiver/2) is a qt forum topic on this, as stated what you want is kind of against the signal slot idiom as such. If you want to invoke explicit thread, why not simply make a method that you can call directly and that would for example wake up the thread from a wait and do some work? Do you need to have a cross-platform solution?

Comment: Thought you got my question wrong there, sorry. At first i thought there could only be one thread running at the same time this way. But it is just the processing signal i have to disconnect and reconnect to one of the threads, and keep the one responsible for the return active at all of them, correct? Thanks again

Comment: @yonobi yes, you are right, all the threads are running but only one is receiving signals at a given moment:) So my suggestion is helpful then? Still, seems like a weird scenario to me, but then again, every pipeline has it's purpose.

Comment: Because i don't know how to call a thread directly this way, sorry i'm new too qt and especially multithreading in general. yes, i think it is helpful thanks, will have to figure out if it works the way i think. Different approach to this scenario would be interesting aswell.

Comment: @yonobi So is Qt a must have as a framework? I mean, in Windows this could be easily achieved with events, I can provide a snippet, but that is why I asked if you need cross-platform code.

Comment: Qt is not a must, but linux is and cross-platform would be nice in general.

Comment: @yionobi Ok I actually made a Qt based consumer/producer sample for you, hope it helps

Comment: @yionobi, actually I shouldn't have written any code so late, looking at it now it's plain wrong:) I'll update and fix the sample during today so you have something to begin with.

Comment: @yonobi, so I updated the example here and on github, try it out

Comment: I did already and adapted it to my needs now, everything works as expected. I can only thank you from the bottom of my heart again :)

Comment: @yonobi, one more thing with this - using the index is ok only the work is evenly distributed, otherwise there might be a situation that a thread that already is doing some work is burdened with new tasks while others are idle. Actually a stack with the indexes of idle threads would be better (where the index is pushed back on the stack when the thread notifies about completion). That is why is mentioned the `notify_one` thing, since there all workers can wait for work, and one is woken up when new work arrives.